# Is package installation in PyCharm usually slower than installation in Anaconda?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I created a venv through Anaconda and connected it into **PyCharm** as a project interpreter.

I'm trying to install packages from Settings(*- Project interpreter - + button - search a package - click 'install'*) in PyCharm, such as **TensorFlow** and **beautifulsoup4**, and this is insanely slow. 
(I'm not sure it is working slowly but correctly because I quit to install it after a long time passes).
When I tried to install TensorFlow in PyCharm terminal, it succeeds in a few minutes.

Now I'm trying to install beautifulsoup4 through Settings, but it stuck. When I see a background task, it shows "*conda update -n base defaults conda*" and a working hard blue bar.

Is package installation from Settings usually slower than using PyCharm terminal or using Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: Not sure what causes this issue, but I had the same problem (on Linux) and found out that many other reported extremely long waiting times when using `conda install ..` or `conda update ..`. I solved it using `pip` for installing new modules. Maybe your pycharm uses pip?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and Yes, when I tried to use pip to install tensorflow, it worked. However, when I try to use Settings for installation, it requires extremely long time. (Beautifulsoup4 is still being installed over 1 hour.... I'm not sure if it will be installed eventually). I hope I have a solution for it.